# how to zip the output of the mysqldump command?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, zip, pipe, mysql

I have a cron with

```
#!/bin/sh

#string representation for current day
day=$(date +%Y%m%d)

#archive db content
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=db_host --user=db_user --password=db_pass db_name | /bin/gzip -c -9 > ${day}_db_name.gz
```

which runs just fine.
However, I would like to create a zip file instead using the zip compression.

I tried with

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=db_host --user=db_user --password=db_pass db_name | zip -q -9 > ${day}_db_name.zip
```

and the result is an archive with a file named "**-**" inside.
My question is how can I change that name into something like the previous command generated, **20130725_db_name**?

It says [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/zip.1.html) something about zip and input and pipeing and "Streaming input and output" but, unfortunately, that's too much for me to understand

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you specify filenames within a zip when creating it on the command line from a pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019603/how-do-you-specify-filenames-within-a-zip-when-creating-it-on-the-command-line-f)

Comment: Try "... | zip -q -9 ${day}_db_name.zip -"

Comment: @TeTeT thank you for trying to solve it, unfortunately that dash generates these errors: `zip error: Nothing to do! (-)` and `mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write`

Comment: @Jay yes it's a similar question but it's not answered.. i mean i tried `zip -q output.zip -@` and got similar errors like those above. from what the top answer said it can not be done in one line and with output pipeing. unfortunately python scripting is not an option for me. but thank you for pointing that out :)