# Is there a way add a file to a .zip with the file content taking from stdin?

Tags: zip

`zip` has `-@` which takes file names from stdin. I just want to add one file with the content taken from stdin. The filename stored in the zip file should be specified in the command line. I don't think that this is possible with the `zip` command line. Could anybody confirm if this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54702078/2030808

Comment: No. This does not do the thing that I need. Did you try it?

Comment: Of course I did! It needs two steps to achieve what you want, but it is as good as you will get if your requirement is to use the infozip implementation of the zip command.

Comment: I need to get it done in one step. I don’t want to create any temp files.

Comment: If you requirement is to use the zip command, you are out of luck. if you can use something else to create the zip file then there is at least one option that will create the zip file in one step.