# Is it possible to specify a file name inside .zip archive compressing standard input to standard output using cli tools?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, streaming

I'm trying to find a way to specify a file name in a compressed .zip archive while compressing it from standard input to standard output. I want to achieve it without creating a temporal file during a process.

Currently I have an example script which creates mysqldump, passes the result as input to a zip command and outputs the stream to aws s3 command to save a result to S3.

Here is the example:

```
mysqldump ... | zip | aws s3 cp - s3://[bucket_name]/output.sql.zip
```

The problem is zip by default saves a file inside zip archive with name "-".

Maybe there is a way how to pass specific file name inside an archive using zip command or any other zip library?

Comment: Your question has already been answered [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2019603/1673776). From what I can see through the answers, the answer would be _no, it's not possible, and your best bet is to use a named FIFO_. Check out the answers to the question I linked please.

Comment: Thanks for the link with a same problem. But I asked maybe there are alternative libs which could help this problem if zip cannot do that.

Comment: Just curious - what is the problem with a named FIFO? You can still have it as a one-line command. Are there any blockers in using that?

Answer (score 0):

Recent Linux distributions have a `streamzip` script which I wrote to handle this usecase. In the example below the `-member` commandline option sets the member within the streamed zipfile to `data.sql`

```
mysqldump ... | streamzip -member data.sql | aws s3 cp - s3://[bucket_name]/output.sql.zip
```

If the `mysqldump` is larger than 4G, include the `-zip64` option with `streamzip`.

If you don't have `streamzip` available download from https://github.com/pmqs/IO-Compress/blob/master/bin/streamzip

Comment: _Recent Linux distributions have a streamzip script which I wrote_ What do you mean by this? Is your script included in some Linux distributions? If so, why does the OP need to clone it from GitHub?

Comment: Yes, it is included in some Linux distributions.  -- I 'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and `streamzip` is present. I don't know which version of Linux have it, so providing a fall-back option to fetch the script.